# How to fetch URL of newly opened tab through javaScript

Tags: javascript, html, google-visualization

I am trying to fetch the URL of the new opened tab.

I am converting the google graph api to image using grchartimg library and then take the image and embed it into PDF. Now there is a library function - **grChartImg.ShowImage('chart_div')**.

When I call this function through onclick event the browser opens a new tab which has a very long base64 encoded URL and contains the image of the graph. I want to fetch the URL of this page.

I have tried window.location, location.href but not getting any success.
The code is shown below..

```
<div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
<a href="javascript:grChartImg.ShowImage('chart_div');">ShowImage</a>
```

Here 'chart_div' is div id of google graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No** you cant do it. You can only use `(window.location.href)` or `(window.parent.location.href)` to fetech the url of the current window and its parent window respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you cannot access another tab's URL; the security within the browser does not allow it.

Your mention of grChartImg leads me to the documentation at http://chartstoimage.eu/#. For the `ShowImage` method, it appears that what you're after isn't possible without making changes to the grChartImg source code.

However, there is another method you may want to consider: `GetImageData`. From the documentation,

```
    grChartImg.SetImageFormat = {type:'png'};

    var imageData=grChartImg.GetImageData('container_div_name');
    imgElement.src=imageData;
```

This `imageData` may be the value you're after.

Comment: I looked up at this but couldn't resolve the purpose.. What I am doing now is downloading the image using DownloadImage function and then changing its name using rename() php function and then loading the image from that particular folder..

Thanks for the help...